# PDF.JS PDF is not rendering properly, appears mirrored and upside down

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm trying to get pdf.js to work in IE. I've copied the code almost exactly from the "Hello World using base64 encoded PDF" example on the pdf.js site at https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/. The PDF is upside down and mirrored. I've looked around and a common cause of this is re-using the canvas for multiple renders, but I'm not doing that I'm just rendering once, so I really have no idea.

At the top of my html document i have:

```
$html .= '<canvas width="600px" height="2000px" id="the-canvas"></canvas>';
```

Then I've basically copied the JS exactly from the demo like so (encodedString variable is my pdf base64 string)

```
        var pdfData = atob(encodedString);

        // Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
        var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

        // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

        // Using DocumentInitParameters object to load binary data.
        var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
        loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
            console.log('PDF loaded');

            // Fetch the first page
            var pageNumber = 1;
            pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {

                console.log('Page loaded');

                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                //canvas.height = viewport.height;
                //canvas.width = viewport.width;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };

                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                    console.log('Page rendered');
                });

            });
        }, function (reason) {
            // PDF loading error
            console.error(reason);
        });
```

The only thing i really changed was i commented out a couple of lines setting the canvas width and height based on viewport, because it wasnt working it was always collapsed, so instead i specified width and height inline with the canvas html.

I cant seem to include images with this new stack overflow design but the pdf is rendering and appears, but its upside down and the text is mirrored, like you're looking at the text in a mirror.

If anyone could give me advice i'd appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Have you checked the PDF data? Decode and save it to a file and make sure it's not actually reversed

Comment: yes i've used the pdfs created many times in other ways trying for a solution to get it to work in IE. They always render properly when i try using other means to load the pdf in chrome for example. And if i open the pdf using other ways in IE it looks ok as well. But i really need this solution to work

Comment: Which version of PDF.js are you using? How are you including the main script in your page?

Comment: i downloaded the pre-built package just now, so its the latest version i guess. i included "pdf.js" then "pdf.worker.js" in script tags

Answer (score 13):

Change {scale: scale} to scale. It wants a number not an object. Example docs are wrong.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem!. They should update the docs if thats the case.

Answer (score 2):

> The method signature changed in PR #10369, hence:

> In version 2.0.943 and earlier it takes "regular" parameters, i.e.
> formatted as getViewport(scale, rotate, dontFlip).

> In version 2.1.266 and later it takes an object, i.e. formatted as
> getViewport({ scale, rotation, dontFlip })

Source:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10809

PR:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/10369

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with flipped PDFs (v3.11.174) . If i set scale to anything except 1 it does show upside down and i have to set dontFlip: false to make it work which seems not intuitive.

```
#both upside down
const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 2});
const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 0.5});

# works
const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 2, dontFlip: false});
const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1});
```

If anybody cares for the full nextjs 13+ example page (it needs pdf.worker.min.js to be copied over to the public folder, iam using     "pdfjs-dist" version 3.11.174",
):

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState<string | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window)

    const getPdf = async (fileId: string) => {
      const pdfFile = await fetch(`/api/pdf/${fileId}`).then(res => res.blob())
      const pdfBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile)
      setPdfUrl(pdfBlobUrl)
    }

    getPdf('0016c2df0d5ebdbfdeab6cce2830a748')

  }, []
  )


  useEffect(() => {

    const loadAndRender = async () => {

      const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
      pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = window.location.origin + '/pdf.worker.min.js';

      const pdf = await pdfJS.getDocument(pdfUrl).promise;

      const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 2, dontFlip: false });

      // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions.
      if (canvasRef.current) {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context.
        const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
        await page.render(renderContext);
      }
    }

    loadAndRender()

  }, [pdfUrl])

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ height: '100vh' }} onClick={() => console.log('canvas clicked')} />;
}
```

with /api/[filename]/route.ts being:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params }) {
  try {
    // Specify the path to the PDF file within the public directory
    const filePath = join(process.cwd(), 'pdfs', `${params.filename}.pdf`);
    // Read the PDF file as a binary object
    const data = await fs.readFile(filePath);

    // Create a response with the PDF binary data
    const response = new NextResponse(data, {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': data.length.toString(),
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${params.filename}.pdf"`,
      },
    });

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to load PDF:', error);
    return new NextResponse('Failed to load PDF', { status: 500 });
  }
}
```